# Increase width in UL list bullets

Tags: html, css, list, styles, html-lists

how to style UL list bullets.
I'm using squares and all I need is to increase width. Is there any way how to do it except using custom images ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, using `::before` and using `content` CSS:

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: -0.67em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: @JZK You can add some `border-radius` and `border-color` to make it more vibrant... `:D`